# Is it possible to get different results on `$?` on the same command?

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script where I'm executing a node command which is meant to be executed by a TFS 2013 Build:

```
node "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\app\Proj\App_Build\r.js" -o "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\app\Proj\App_Build\build-styles.js"
$success = $?
if (!$success){
    exit 1
}
```

When I run this script manually and the command fails `$success` is `false` and the script `exits 1`, but when the build executes the script and the `node` command fails, `$success` (and `$?`) is `true`.

What can change the behavior of powershell? I have no idea what else to try. So far I eliminated the following:

1. Changed the Build Service user to the same Admin user that executes the script manually
2. Tried executing the command with `cmd /c node ...`
3. Tried executing the command with `Start-Process node...`
4. Ran the Build Service interactively
5. Ran the build with both VSO Build Controller and an on premise Build Controller
6. Executed the script manually with the same command used by TFS (per the Build Log)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can we restructure this a bit so we have a better feel for what is happening? I tend to avoid $? because it is harder to debug and test with.

```
try
{
    Write-Host "TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY = $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY"
    $result = node "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\app\Proj\App_Build\r.js" -o "$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\app\Proj\App_Build\build-styles.js"
    Write-Host "Result = $result"
}
catch
{
    Write-Error "Command failed"
    Exit 1
}
```

Sometimes I wrap my command in a  `Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait` just to see if that generates a different error message.

In your case, I would also try `Enter-PSSession` to get a non-interactive prompt on the TFS server. I have seen cases where powershell acts diferently when the shell is not interactive.